# Facing issue with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, antd

I am trying to create a table for inventory using ant design. I have used react redux to manage few states. Below is the given code

```
import { Table } from 'antd';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {loadData} from '../../features/DataTableState/DataTableSlice';
const DataTable = () => {

  const gridData = useSelector((state) => state.dataTable.isGridData);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.dataTable.isLoading);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadData());
  },[dispatch]);


  const columns = [
    {
      title:'Id',
      dataIndex:'Id',
      align:'center',
    },
    {
      title:'product',
      dataIndex:'name',
      align:'center',
      editTable:true
    },
    {
      title:'description',
      dataIndex:'email',
      align:'center',
      editTable:true
    },
    {
      title:'inventory',
      dataIndex:'age',
      align:'center',
      editTable:false
    },
    {
      title:'Action',
      dataIndex:'action',
      align:'center',
    }

  ];

  return (
    <div className='data-table'>
     data table
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataTable
```

Slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const dataTableSlice = createSlice({
  name: "dataTable",
  initialState: {
    isGridData: [],
    isLoading: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    loadData: async (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
      );
      state.isGridData(response.data);
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
  },
});

export const { loadData } = dataTableSlice.actions;

export default dataTableSlice.reducer;
```

store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import menuReducer from "../features/MenuState/menuSlice";
import dataTableReducer from "../features/DataTableState/DataTableSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    menu: menuReducer,
    dataTable: dataTableReducer,
  },
});
```

As soon as I am using useEffect or creating any other function with in the component my webpage is going blank as soon as I am deleting the created functions the page is going back to normal.
I am unable to sort the issue

Comment: Do you get an error in the console area? if yes then share your error

Comment: This is the error I am getting:                                                                           
 Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: dataTable.isLoading. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"dataTable/loadData"}.

Comment: Please add reducer slice, and store code. Are you using react-router-dom

Comment: I  have added the slice and store and yes I am using react-router-dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducers cannot be async. Instead, move your async logic into an async thunk and use the `extraReducers` argument.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

export const dataTableSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dataTable',
  initialState: {
    isGridData: [],
    isLoading: false,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadData.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(loadData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isGridData = [...action.payload.data];
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
  },
});

export const loadData = createAsyncThunk('loadData', async () => {
  return await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');
});

export default dataTableSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Line 11:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: @jhansimahato I've updated the code to fix the type error

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe it shows this error because you don't add value in correct manner into the array

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const dataTableSlice = createSlice({
 name: "dataTable",
 initialState: {
 isGridData: [],
 isLoading: false,
},
reducers: {
 loadData: async (state) => {
  state.isLoading = true;
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
  );
  state.isGridData.push(response.data);
  state.isLoading = false;
 },
},
});

export const { loadData } = dataTableSlice.actions;

export default dataTableSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: I have tried this as well still I am facing the same issue

Comment: can you add your code into the code sandbox then I will check  it will be helpful.

Comment: Add your code and provide a link in the comment section I will check tomorrow.

Comment: sure. I will add the link here